# Read, sort, and re-write a file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

You are provided the following list that contains (semi random) years from modern history. Save the list to a text file named “events.txt”. Write a program in Java that:

1. Reads in the file “events.txt”
2. Sorts it with the latest events first
3. Determines whether the founding of CMU in 1892 was considered a world historic event
4. If not so yet, adds the event to the list of events
5. Writes the new list of events to a file named “sorted_events.txt”

part of the list looks like this:

1066

1095

1100

1206

1215

I have written this code but there is an error in the main method, not sure what it is. Also, if there is a more simple way to code this please let me know! This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment6 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("events.txt");
    FileReader read = new FileReader(file);
        LineNumberReader lines = new LineNumberReader(read);
        Scanner readIn = new Scanner(file);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("sorted_events.txt");

        try{

            if (file.exists()){
                int lineNumber = 0;
                while (lines.readLine() != null){
                    lineNumber++;
                }
                int[] event = new int[lineNumber];
                int j = 0;
                while(readIn.hasNext()){
                    event[j]=readIn.nextInt();
                    j++;
                }
                Arrays.sort(event);
                boolean found = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < event.length; i++){
                    if (event[i] == 1892){
                        System.out.println("CMU is a historic event.");
                        found = true;
                    }

                    if (found == false){
                        addElement(event, 1892);
                    }
                }
                int[] sortedEvent = new int[lineNumber];
                for (int k = 0; k < event.length; k++){
                    sortedEvent[k] = event[(event.length-1) - k];
                    System.out.println(sortedEvent[k]);
                }
                for (int print = 0; print < event.length; print++){
                    output.println(sortedEvent[print]);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("File does not exist.");
            }
            readIn.close();
            output.close();
            lines.close();
}
catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace(); }
}


static int[] addElement(int[] a, int e) {
    a = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);
    a[a.length - 1] = e;
    return a;
}
}
```

Comment: You should make a greater effort when asking than "not sure what the problem is".

Comment: At least don't copy/paste the whole instruction of a homework instructions in the question

Comment: I get an error with the boolean found, it says the local variable found is not used.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from the same file with both a `LineNumberReader` and a `Scanner`. If you want to know how many lines the file has before processing its content, you will have to close the file after you count the lines and open it again.

For example:

```
try{ 
    int linesCount = 0;
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""))) {
        while (br.readLine() != null) {
            linesCount++;
         }
    }
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(""))) {
        int[] arr = new int[linesCount];
        int index = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            arr[index] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or, if you are allowed to use `List`s, you can do this:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(""))) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        list.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```